# An alien species that doesn't need to drink liquids?

Tags: xenobiology, food

Nearly all life on Earth needs to drink water to survive. But what if my alien species only needs to eat to get by?

Comment: Some animals don't drink.  https://www.toknowisgood.com/2019/01/04/animals-that-don-t-drink-water.html

Comment: Probably the best known land animal which does not drink water at all is the [kangaroo rat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_rat) of North America. And of course almost all amphibians do not drink any water -- their problem is the opposite, how to get rid of the water which comes in through their skin by osmosis.

Comment: reptiles are really good at this, unlike mammals they don't loose water through urine because they don't urinate, making solid uric acid instead. this is why there are so many desert reptiles.

Answer (score 8):

## Already done by nature

Cetaceans do not drink the water they are immersed in. The amount of salt in the ocean would dehydrate them. [They obtain their water exclusively from food](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-can-sea-mammals-drink/):

> Although some marine mammals are known to drink seawater at least on occasion, it is not well established that they routinely do so. They have other options: sea-dwelling mammals can get water through their food, and they can produce it internally from the metabolic breakdown of food (water is one of the by-products of carbohydrate and fat metabolism).

If a whale cannot find food for too long, it will not only display signs of hunger, but also dehydration as well.